Typescript incorrectly assumes that an element 'could be' undefined
Suppose the following:
interface HandleMapDefaultProps {
    item: {
        id: number
    } & Record<string, unknown>;
    renderCustomComponent?: never;
}

interface HandleMapCustomProps {
    renderCustomComponent: () => HTMLElement;
    item?: never;
}

type HandleMapProps = HandleMapDefaultProps | HandleMapCustomProps;
const handleMap = ({
    item,
    renderCustomComponent
} : HandleMapProps): HTMLElement => renderCustomComponent?.() ?? <div>{item.id}</div>

This throws an error,
'item' is possibly 'undefined'

However according to the type provided for props (MapProps), if renderCustomComponent is undefined, then item will always be defined.
Doing item!.id fixes this, but I'm wondering if there's a better way?

Instead of using optional properties of type never omit that those properties the corresponding members of the union. In other words, declare them when they will have a value

What is the definition of MapProps type? And it looks like type definitions provided are not used in the code

HandleMapProps, not MapProps, fixed

It seems like TypeScript is not able to infer through optional chaining function calls like this. You can instead use a ternary operator which works for me:
interface HandleMapDefaultProps {
  item: {
    id: number;
  } & Record<string, unknown>;
  renderCustomComponent?: never;
}

interface HandleMapCustomProps {
  renderCustomComponent: () => HTMLElement;
  item?: never;
}

type HandleMapProps = HandleMapDefaultProps | HandleMapCustomProps;

const handleMap = ({
  item,
  renderCustomComponent,
}: HandleMapProps): HTMLElement | number =>
  renderCustomComponent ? renderCustomComponent() : item.id;

(I modified the return type for this example because in my environment JSX elements don't return HTMLElement. The code above is able to infer that item must be defined.)
Playground

Yes, TS only knows how to do narrowing in specifically supported ways.  Given that here we want  renderCustomComponent to act as the discriminant of a destructured discriminated union, the best way to do that is to check renderCustomComponent directly for truthiness instead of logically through an optional chaining function call.
